# Issue with SP2013 External List ID Column and SP2013 Views

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

I am having a weird issue with an External Content Type ID column when added to the view causes the view to drop into SP2010 branding (with new button at the bottom). When I remove the ID from the view it has the SharePoint 2013 branding with the "add new" link and view selector. I have another list based on another ECT and it doesn't exhibit this behavior. The Monthly Totals ECT with the ID column I am having issues with but the Assessment ECT works with the record ID . ID column is a primary key, int, not null value in the DB. Anybody have ideas?

This is where it works without the ID column.

[image: without ID column]

This is 2010 SharePoint branding due to adding the ID column. It is missing the new item textbox as well as the view picker. The add new green cross is at the bottom 
[image: with id column]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not related to adding the ID column. it's related to the `default view`. which confirms that you have another list that is working properly as you have mentioned in your question.

Now you need to show the external list `Add New Item` link at the **Top** of the list as SharePoint 2013, not at the bottom of the list as SharePoint 2010. So try to do the following:

- Open your External List.
- From the above ribbon,> Click on List Settings > Create a new view > set it as default view > select your view column.
- Save your view, go back to your list it should be now working properly!

**Default view**

`Add New Item` link at the **bottom** as shown below

[image]

**New view**

`Add New Item` link at the **top** as shown below

[image]